# strange behavior of left shifting with char variable in C

Tags: c, char, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am trying to left shifting with char variable. It's giving strange output. According to C standard, Range of signed char is 127 to -128, So I output will be -128 of following program but it's printing 640.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 5;
    
    printf("%d\n", (c << 7));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Is it undefined behavior?

Online compiler : [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hOrJd4g7MPsEAcKd)

Comment: When used in expressions and passed as argument to a varargs function like `printf`, all`char` types will be *promoted* to an `int`. Including sign-extension. To print it as a small integer use `%hhd`.

Comment: Also, it's *implementation defined* (i.e. up to the compiler) if `char` is signed or unsigned. For bitwise expression I recommend you use explicit unsigned types, i.e. `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I don't really know why bit-shifting works in one scenario but not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433792/i-dont-really-know-why-bit-shifting-works-in-one-scenario-but-not-the-other)

Comment: [shifting an unsigned char by more than 8 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62666302/995714)

Comment: *"...Size of signed char is 127 to -128"* -- wrong! The size is 1 byte, it (signed char) can store values ranging from 127 to -128.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is implicitly type casted to  `int` type. That's why you are getting unexpected output.

Type cast explicitly to get expected output.

```
printf("%d\n", (char) (c << 7));
```

Or

You can do this

```
c = (char)(c<< 7);
```

Comment: Doesn't help since the value will be promoted to an `int` again (with sign extension) when passed to `printf`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you. I did correction.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. "...but it's printing 640..." ?

Since the 8-bit binary number for 5 is 00000101, `c << 7` results in a 32-bit binary number `0...(other 20 0s)...01010000000`, which is 640 in decimal.

#### 2. "...Is it undefined behavior..." ?

**No**, the behavior is defined by the standard. This behavior consists of two major processes, one is *Bitwise
Shift Operators*, and the other is *Integer Promotions*.

For *Bitwise Shift Operators*, in C99 6.5.7 p3:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.

For *Integer Promotions*, in C99 6.3.1.1 p2:

> An object or expression with an integer type  whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less
> than or equal to the rank of **int** and **unsigned int**.
> If an **int** can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an **int**;

Accoding to these definitions, the result of `c << 7` would eventually be an `int` type number 640, whose bit pattern is `0...(other 20 0s)...01010000000`.

One workaround is doing as **what @msc suggested**, that is, `(char) c << 7`, which has the effect that roughly described as follows:

```sh
#1: (char)c<<7  

   ——————> 0...(other 20 0s)...01010000000  
   ——————> (Promotion & Truncation happened)
   ——————> 10000000   

#2: %d

   ——————> (Promotion & Sign Extension happened)
   ——————> 1...(other 20 1s)...11110000000  
  
#3: printf  

   ——————> 1...(other 20 1s)...11110000000   ->   -128
```